# STIntersects between SqlGeography types in a condition IF

Tags: c#, sqlgeography

I use the SqlGeography type.

Is there a difference between the following uses of STIntersects function:

```
this.Location.STIntersects(another.Location)
```

and

```
this.Location.STIntersects(another.Location).Value
```

and

```
this.Location.STIntersects(another.Location).Equals(1)
```

?

I get different results.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the [SqlIntersects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.stintersects.aspx) method doesn't return a bool, it returns a [SqlBoolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlboolean.value(v=vs.110).aspx) structure

Assuming your geographies intersect, I would assume you get the following values:

this.Location.STIntersects(another.Location) => true

this.Location.STIntersects(another.Location).Value => returns value proprerty of SqlBoolean return value => true

this.Location.STIntersects(another.Location).Equals(1) => compares SqlBoolean structure to value 1, and returns false

Answer (score 0):

Matthew Evans has given complete answer. Here is same answer phrased differently.

- `Location.STIntersects(another.Location)` returns a [SqlBoolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933962.aspx) with `true` in it if the locations intersect otherwise it returns a `false`.
- `Location.STIntersects(another.Location).Value` returns `true` or `false` of type [System.Boolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlboolean.value(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than SqlBoolean above.
- `Location.STIntersects(another.Location).Equals(1)` returns "[*true if object is an instance of SqlBoolean and the two are equal; otherwise, false.*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k12a7az(v=vs.110).aspx)". Hence it will always return false the way you are comparing.

Comment: `public static Area GetEnabledArea(IDatabaseConnection database, SqlGeography location)
        {
            return database.GetData<Area>().Where(a => a.Enabled && a.Border.STIntersects(location).Equals(1)).FirstOrDefault();
        }` gives me my enabled area for which "location" intersects ... That's what I find strange.

Comment: The LINQ in this method is supposed to return the first or default element of `database.GetData<Area>()` which satisfies the condition `a.Enabled && a.Border.STIntersects(location).Equals(1)`.

Comment: @profou: If I read it in simple english, with this call you are essentially asking for the first `Area` type data which is `Enabled` and whose border intersects with the `location` received in the method. Since you are comparing using `Equals(1)`, it will be false for all `Area`s in your database and in effect return the default `Area` element every time the method is called.

Comment: @profou: I haven't tested as I don't have `SqlGeogrpahy` data with me, but try this: `a.Border.STIntersects(location).Value == 1` OR just `a.Border.STIntersects(location)`.